# Why the lambda funct checks the Series's index instead of its value?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have created a Series using:

```
suits = list('HSCD')
card_val = (list(range(1, 11)) + [10] * 3) * 4
base_names = ['A'] + list(range(2, 11)) + list('JKQ')
cards = []
for suit in list('HSCD'):
    cards.extend(str(num) + suit for num in base_names)

deck = pd.Series(card_val, index=cards)

deck.head(15)

AH      1
2H      2
3H      3
4H      4
5H      5
6H      6
7H      7
8H      8
9H      9
10H    10
JH     10
KH     10
QH     10
AS      1
2S      2
dtype: int64
```

Now I would like to draw 5 samples for Monte Carlo simulation purposes using next function:

```
def draw(deck, n=5):
    return deck.sample(n)
draw(deck)

JD    10
7C     7
3S     3
JS    10
3C     3
dtype: int64
```

Next I'd like to draw 2 cards from each suit (H, S, C, D) by using following code:

```
deck.groupby(lambda x: x[-1]).apply(draw, n=2)
```

The output:

```
C  8C      8
   3C      3
D  3D      3
   KD     10
H  3H      3
   JH     10
S  9S      9
   10S    10
dtype: int64
```

How come the lambda funct checks the Series index instead of the value?
I expected an error, because (I thought) the lambda funct's equivalent to the following codes:

```
a = 10
a[-1]
```

Thanks in advance for clarifying that.

Comment: according to the [official doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) function is indeed applied to the index: *If by is a function, it’s called on each value of the object’s index.*

Comment: It's really important to understand that the fact you are using a lambda expression to create a function object to pass to `groupby` is *completely irrelevant* to your question. It is an implementation detail, an unimportant one. You'd get the exact same behavior if you created a function using a function definition statement (because **both create the exact same type of object**)